# Using Object class Reference variable, accessing different class members.

Tags: java, object

I am trying to access class members of different class i.e.,getDetails() from student as well as customer class using Object class Reference variable. But it looks like its not working. Please look into this easy code and help me out how to access the getDetails() using Object class ob[0] and ob[1]

```
class Customer
{
    int custId;
    String name;
    Customer(String name, int custId)
    {
        this.custId = custId;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void getDetails()
    {
        System.out.println(this.custId+" : "+this.name);   
    }

}
class Student
    {
        int roll;
        String name;
        Student(String name, int roll)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.roll = roll;       
        }
        public void getDetails()
        {
            System.out.println(this.roll+" : "+this.name);
        }
        public static void main(String []args)
        {
            Object[] ob = new Object[2];
            ob[0] = new Student("Vishal", 041);
            ob[1] = new Customer("Xyz" , 061);
            ob[0].getDetails();
            ob[1].getDetails();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a common interface that declares the method getDetails. Something like this:

```
public interface Person {
    public void getDetails();
}
```

Let Student and Customer implement the interface. Then declare the array like this:

```
Person ent[] ob = new Person[2];
....
```